# Photography Business, Getting Clients

Tags: digital

I was hoping to hear some great tips on how to get clients. The obvious is having great photos but I want to go further into the marketing side. I've also already created a referral program, now I'm just waiting. I don't want to just wait though, I want to keep going and reach out.

One example being finding engaged couples or expecting mothers on Instagram. How do you reach out to personal accounts on instagram? How do you FIND them? Hashtag examples?

How do you reach out to your facebook friends without sounding desperate? I don't think many people see my posts offering services. I want to reach out to my friends asking if they are in need of any photos.

If you have any other ideas, I would love to know!

Comment: What's your digital marketing budget, in both time and money. How many hours per day can you spend creating ads and posting content and how much can you afford to spend per week?

Comment: Related, similar question: [Ways to obtain new portrait photography clients?](//photo.stackexchange.com/q/88164)

Comment: "The obvious is having great photos..." Not based on what I've seen. Those with the most business in my area are the ones with adequate photo skills and excellent marketing skills and social connections.

Comment: Like crack: give it away at first, until people come to you begging to shoot their events and portraits. nobody wants a half-ad on facebook, but if they see a gorgeous photo of a bride, they will ask who took it.

Comment: @dandavis Good luck with that. Once you become the "free" photographer you'll always be expected to be the "free" photographer. The second question out of their mouth after "Who took that?" is "How much did you have to pay?"

Comment: Any business draws its clients from a large pool of people. Who exactly from that large pool will end up becoming a client depends on many random factors, so you can't go about approaching people and expect a high success rate for recruiting clients. You need to advertise your business on a large scale, e.g. print out a few hundred flyers every day and distribute them in your local neighborhood, it will take just an hour a day or less. After 3 months you'll have distributed 10,000 flyers, and it becomes quite likely that some of the people who have seen your add will have contacted you.